# What's the default resolution for minecraft texture packs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to add a texture pack for Minecraft but I don't know what the default texture resolution is, as I don't want HD packs.

Should I look for texture packs that are 16x16 or 32x32 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default texture resolution is 16x16.

Until Minecraft version 1.5, a client mod was required for higher resolutions.

Comment: I'm curious — do true low-res packs (where each block/item is e.g. 1 pixel, not 16x16 pixels of the same color) also require a "high"-res mod?

Comment: @Ben Well, I'd assume they do _not_ in fact use just one pixel, but instead use 16 pixels of the same color.

Comment: @Jake King — There are both kinds.  Hence the distinction.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The default resolution of Minecraft Vanilla (=unmodded) is 16x16 pixels. Any textures with higher resolution than 16x16 is called HD. Current version of Minecraft supports HD textures out of the box, just add the resource pack of your choice.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Texture

Answer (score 1):

16x16 is default and I believe larger scales may work.